# Get numeric output with parsel

Tags: python, css, parsel

I'm trying to parse a numeric field using parsel. By default, the documentation shows how to extract text. And this:

```py
from parsel import Selector
html = "<title>2</title>\n"
selector = Selector(text=html)
get_text = selector.css("title::text").get()
print(type(get_text))
```

Returns `str`. However,

```py
print(selector.css("title::number").get())
```

gives the error

```py
cssselect.xpath.ExpressionError: The pseudo-element ::number is unknown
```

Is there an easy way to extract numbers using parsel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lxml, because parcel conversion return `str` result.

```
from lxml import etree
xml = etree.XML('<title>2</title>\n')
find = etree.XPath('number(//title/text())')
result = find(xml)
print(result)
print(type(result))
```

output:

```
2.0

<class 'float'>
```